# how to invoke fonts dir in ghostscript

Tags: shell, fonts, command-prompt, ghostscript

I am trying to create a PDF out of a text file with Courier as font and trying to use gswin32c.exe on Windows, but unnable to pass parameters correctly, I think. The gswin32c.exe is the Windows exe of Ghostscript.

Here is my command:

```
gswin32c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH="C:\Temp\Fonts2\" -sOUTPUTFILE="C:\Temp\Outputfile.pdf" A1401227.TXT
```

I don't get a output file, why? How can I trigger the Font, pass the fonts dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting an output file is nothign to do with the presence or absence of fonts.

You appear to be sending a text file to GS, which it can't handle (unless this is hand-crafted PostScript).

Most likely you are generating an error, but because you have specified -dBATCH the application exits immediately after displaying it, so you can't see it. Try it without that switch.